# using Ubuntu 10.10 I want my speakers and head phones as separate devices

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio, ubuntu-10.10

I would like it if I could set my rear speaker jack, not surround sound rear, to be used as the system default only. I want the head phones, that plug into the front of my PC, to be silent, unless I tell a program to use that output, such as VoIP.

I am able to do this when running Windows7, so the hard is able to do what I want it to do. Under Win7 I use the realtek manager to set them to run as separate devices, the rear speakers are set as the system default, but I can change it the front output. Then my VoIP application is able to be set to ring on all audio devices, so my main speakers and headphones, but I only hear the conversation in my headphones.

I know that not all applications are able to set them selves to play on different hardware devices, but if I could just get them to only play on the main speakers that would be cool. Even better if I was able to some where set that I want 'programX' to play through the headphones.

Note that although I have been saying rear speakers, this is just a stereo set up. They are just normal speakers (a hi-fi) plugged into the rear jack on my PC, I then have a head set plugged into the front of my PC.

Thanks

Comment: I would like to find out the same for Fedora 14. Right now, all I know is that you need to define some pulseaudio sinks and that you can use the `PULSE_SINK` environment variable to specify what sink a program should use.

Comment: Yes, from what I have learnt, it should be a case of configuring pulseAudio correctly. I some how need to get the front headphone socket to be counted as a separate sink to the rear output jacks.